# How to filter comments by ID in jquery?

Tags: jquery, loops, filter, foreach, comments

In this project I want to make a filter for the comments so they will appear for the belonging post by ID. Thank you in advance !

```
 $(function () {
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {

          var params = new window.URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
          var postId = params.get('post');
          var postObj = result.filter(function (postElm) {
            return postId == postElm.id;
          });
          if (postObj.length < 1) {
            alert('post not found');
            return;
          }
          renderPage(postObj[0]);
        }
      });

      function renderPage(post) {
        $("#loop").append(
          "<div  class='card bg-success text-white'>User ID:" + post.userId +
          "<div class='card-header'>ID:" + post.id + "</div>" +
          "<div class='card-body'>" +
          "<a post=" + post.id + "'><h5 class='card-title'>" + post.title + "</h5></a>" +
          "<p class='card-text'>" + post.body + "</p>" + "</div>" +
          "</div>");
      }
      $.getJSON('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments', function (data) {
        data.forEach(comments => {
          var comObj = data.filter(function (comElm) {
            return comElm.id == postId;
            console.log(comElm);
          });
          $("#comm").append(
            `<div class='card bg-secondary text-white'>
                postId: ${comments.postId}
                <h6 class="caard-header ">ID: ${comments.id}
                <div class="caard-body">Name: ${comments.name}
                <p class="email">Email: ${comments.email}</p>
                <p class="form-control comment-text text-white">Body: ${comments.body}</p>
              </div>`
          );
        });
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues with the comments fetch handler.

First, `postId` is not defined within the function. It is defined in the `success` handler of your first `ajax` call, which is a different scope. You need to move it higher-up so that it will be available to both functions. You can put it right after the `$(function () {` line.

Next, the `data` parameter is an array - an array of comments. It doesn't make much sense to perform a `forEach` loop on this array *and then* to perform a `filter` for each iteration of this loop. This performs the same filter operation for as many items as there are in data - ie., *500 times!*

The `comObj` that is the result of the filter is not even used and the filter is wrong because it matches on `comElm.id` instead of `comElm.postId`.

Also, in the `success` handler of your first `ajax` call (for posts) you should use [`.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to return a *single* post instead of filtering to an array of posts.

```js
$(function() {
  // var params = new window.URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  // params.get('post') will return a String,
  // we must convert that to a Number
  // var postId = Number(params.get('post'));
  const postId = 2;
  
  function renderPage(post) {
    $("#loop").append(
      "<div  class='card bg-success text-white'>User ID:" + post.userId +
      "<div class='card-header'>ID:" + post.id + "</div>" +
      "<div class='card-body'>" +
      "<a post=" + post.id + "'><h5 class='card-title'>" + post.title + "</h5></a>" +
      "<p class='card-text'>" + post.body + "</p>" + "</div>" +
      "</div>"
    );
  }
  
  $.getJSON("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", function (posts) {
    // use .find so we get a single post
    const post = posts.find(function(post) {
      return postId == post.id;
    });

    if (post === undefined) {
      alert('post not found');
      return;
    }

    renderPage(post);
  });

  $.getJSON('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments', function(comments) {
    // for each `comment` in `comments`:
    comments.forEach(comment => {
      // if the postId of the comment matches our global `postId`:
      if (comment.postId === postId) {
        $("#comm").append(
          `<div class='card bg-secondary text-white'>
            postId: ${comment.postId}
            <h6 class="caard-header ">ID: ${comment.id}</h6>
            <div class="caard-body">
              Name: ${comment.name}
              <p class="email">Email: ${comment.email}</p>
              <p class="form-control comment-text text-white">Body: ${comment.body}</p>
            </div>`
         );
       }
     });
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="loop"></div>
<div id="comm"></div>
```